# PHP Multiple digits regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to extract the digits from the following string using regular expression:

pc 32444 xbox 43567

so my array will be

`array ([0] => 32444 [1] => 43567)`

Can someone help construct a preg_match for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/\d+/
```

But you would need to use `preg_match_all` to get all matches:

```
preg_match_all('/\\d+/', $str, $matches)
```

`$matches[0]` will then contain the array you’re looking for.